# How to deserialize JSON into a structure with a Box<[u8]> value?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I have a struct that needs to include a "bytes" field, and I'm trying to deserialize it from JSON.

When I use `&'a [u8]`, this works, but then I need to add a lifetime annotation to this struct, and the struct that encloses it, and so on.

I thought I'd get around it by having the bytes "owned" and use an enclosing `Box`, but that didn't work. I'm trying to figure out *why not*, or whether there's a way (either with some serde annotations, or a custom helper for this field, or something else) to get this to work.

More concretely, this works:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
  some_field: Option<String>,
  field_of_interest: &'a [u8],
}
```

And this does not:

```rust
struct Foo {
  some_field: Option<String>,
  field_of_interest: Box<[u8]>,
}
```

In both cases, I'm calling it as:

```rust
let my_foo: Foo = serde_json::from_slice(...);
```

I encountered the same issue when replacing `Box` with `Vec` (i.e. as `Vec<u8>`)

*Edit with solution:*

As @lpiepiora pointed out below, this needs an additional wrapper. Something like the following, which is provided by the `serde_bytes` crate:

```rust
#[cfg(any(feature = "std", feature = "alloc"))]
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Box<[u8]> {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer).map(Vec::into_boxed_slice)
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue did you encounter with `Vec`/`Box`?

Comment: @agam I assume you want to deserialize a JSON string into `Box<[u8]>` (because an array would deserialize without a problem). Check out this crate https://docs.serde.rs/serde_bytes/ it should help

Comment: The owned version of a slice is a `Vec`. Did you try `Vec<u8>` (without brackets) ?
If it does not work can you share the JSON ?

Comment: @Co_42 yes, I tried `Vec<u8>`, updated to reflect.

@lpiepiora thank you that worked !! (now I'm going to go understand _why_). Please add a one-line answer so I mark it as the right one :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that you're trying to deserialize JSON string to `Vec<u8>`, you can add a crate [serde_bytes](http://docs.serde.rs/serde_bytes).

For example:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
      a: Option<String>,
      #[serde(with = "serde_bytes")]
      b: Vec<u8>
}

fn main() {
    let x = b"{ \"a\": \"a-value\", \"b\": \"aaaaaaaa\" }";
    let my_foo: Foo = serde_json::from_slice(x).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", my_foo);
}
```

Would print: `Foo { a: Some("a-value"), b: [97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97] }`.

Normally `Vec<u8>` [expects an array](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/6366f17da719a0efa5117c780fdd5469b903929d/serde/src/de/impls.rs#L900).